# Django Rest Framework URL for custom action not working

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls, django-rest-viewsets, django-url-reverse

I've got the following custom action in my view:

```
class OrderAPIViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def create(self, request):
        print("Here: working")

    @action(detail=True, methods=['post'])
    def add(self, request, *arg, **kwargs):
        print("HERE in custom action")
        order = self.get_object()
        print(order)
```

my app's `urls.py` is:

```
from rest_framework import routers
from .views import OrderAPIViewSet


router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'orders', OrderAPIViewSet, basename='order')

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

So in my test when I try to access `orders/post` it works, but when I try to access `orders/{pk}/add` it fails. I mean, the reverse itself is failing:

```
ORDERS_LIST_URL = reverse('order-list')
ORDERS_ADD_URL = reverse('order-add')

class PublicOrderApiTests(TestCase):

   def test_sample_test(self):
       data = {}
       res = self.client.post(ORDERS_ADD_URL, data, format='json')
```

as I said before, I've got a separate test where I use `ORDERS_LIST_URL` like this:

```
res = self.client.post(ORDERS_LIST_URL, data, format='json')
```

but when running the test I'm getting the following error:

> ImportError: Failed to import test module: orders.tests Traceback
> (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 436, in
> _find_test_path
> module = self._get_module_from_name(name)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 377, in
> _get_module_from_name
> **import**(name)   File "/app/orders/tests.py", line 22, in 
> ORDERS_ADD_URL = reverse('order-add')   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 87,
> in reverse
> return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py",
> line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
> raise NoReverseMatch(msg) django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'order-add' with no arguments not found. 2 pattern(s)
> tried: ['orders/(?P[^/.]+)/add\.(?P[a-z0-9]+)/?$',
> 'orders/(?P[^/.]+)/add/$']
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Ran 1 test in 0.000s
>
> FAILED (errors=1)

according to the documentation I shouldn't need to register this endpoint, the router is supposed to do it by itself. What am I missing?

Comment: remove the usage of `reverse(...)` at the module level and bring it to your class level

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that you've missed is `pk` in your reverse. Since the add API needs a `pk` of your Order object, you need to pass it to reverse function. For example:

```
order_add_url = reverse('order-add', kwargs={'pk': 1})
print(order_add_url)  # which will print '/orders/1/add/'
```

So I think you should move this part to the body of `PublicOrderApiTests`'s methods since you need a dynamic url per test object.

Another problem is that the `ViewSet` class does not support `self.get_object()` and if you want to use this method you should either have your own method or use rest framework `GenericViewSet` (i.e. `from rest_framework.viewsets import GenericViewSet` and inherit from this class instead of `ViewSet`) then you can access the `get_object()` method. You can also read more about generic views in [rest framework docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/).

Comment: yes, that was it, thanks. I moved URL consts into `PublicOrderApiTests`. Is there a way to dynamically populate the id or every time I want to call that endpoint I need to do `order_add_url = reverse('order-add', kwargs={'pk': 1})` in the method performing the call? if so, there's no need for the defined const `ORDERS_ADD_URL` right?

Comment: Yes you're right... an easy way to do that (dynamically test purpose) is to first create an `Order` object in your method (i.e. `order_instance = Order.objects.create(required_fields_here`) and then use reverse just after creating an object. For example `order_add_url = reverse('order-add', kwargs={'pk': order_instance.id})`.

Comment: one last question. I thought this method could be used as template to construct other urls but doesn't seem so. I wanted to create a remove endpoint, something like `/order/{order_id}/remove/{item_id}` so I created an `@action` for remove and in my test I defined `url=reverse('order-remove' kwargs={'pk':1,'order_id:'1'}` but it's getting me an error: `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'order-remove' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 12345, 'product_id': 1}' not found.` any idea why?